# Dynamic icon size in Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I use materiel-UI icon

`<ArrowRightAlt/>`

I can control the size of the icon by fontSize

`<ArrowRightAlt fontSize="large" />`

But I want v size to depend on window size (like  md,xs,sm)

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of doing this using [Box](https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box). I'm changing color in addition to font-size just to make it easier to tell which breakpoint it is at.

```
import React from "react";
import ArrowRightAlt from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowRightAlt";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box
      clone
      color={{ xs: "red", sm: "orange", md: "yellow", lg: "green", xl: "blue" }}
      fontSize={{ sm: 48, md: 96, lg: 192, xl: 384 }}
    >
      <ArrowRightAlt />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dynamic icon size]

Related documentation:

- https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box
- https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#object
- https://material-ui.com/system/typography/#font-size
- https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#size